# Spurious wakeups only sometimes occur with std::condition_variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking

I'm trying to demonstrate the spurious wakeup behavior of `std::condition_variable` using a simple program compiled with MSVC (version 19.32.31332, if that matters). However, I have begun to notice that spurious wakeups only occur when the two-argument overload of the `wait` method is used. This appears to be true in both Debug and Release modes.

I can easily detect spurious wakeups with the `Predicate` argument of the two-argument overload:

**Code**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

#define NUM_CVS 6
#define NUM_THREADS 12

std::mutex cout_mutex;

std::mutex m[NUM_CVS];
std::condition_variable cv[NUM_CVS];
bool data[NUM_CVS];

bool check_data(std::size_t i) {
    bool d = data[i];
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(cout_mutex);
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": Woken... " << (d ? "Waited." : "Spurious.") << std::endl;
    }
    return d;
}

void task(std::size_t i) {
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(cout_mutex);
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": Locking..." << std::endl;
    }

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m[i]);

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(cout_mutex);
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": Locked. Waiting..." << std::endl;
    }

    cv[i].wait(l, [&] {return check_data(i); });
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine dre(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> d(0, NUM_CVS - 1);

    std::vector<std::future<void>> v;

    for (auto i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        v.push_back(std::async(task, d(dre)));
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);

    for (auto i = 0; i < NUM_CVS; ++i) {
        auto index = i;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m[index]);
            data[index] = true;
        }
        cv[index].notify_one();
    }

    for (auto& f : v) {
        f.wait();
    }
}
```

**Console Output**

```
25220: Locking...
22672: Locking...
22672: Locked. Waiting...
22672: Woken... Spurious.
26224: Locking...
26224: Locked. Waiting...
26224: Woken... Spurious.
22356: Locking...
22356: Locked. Waiting...
22356: Woken... Spurious.
25220: Locked. Waiting...
25220: Woken... Spurious.
18304: Locking...
18304: Locked. Waiting...
18304: Woken... Spurious.
26544: Locking...
21132: Locking...
21132: Locked. Waiting...
21132: Woken... Spurious.
19144: Locking...
19144: Locked. Waiting...
19144: Woken... Spurious.
21584: Locking...
21584: Locked. Waiting...
21584: Woken... Spurious.
26544: Locked. Waiting...
26544: Woken... Spurious.
25872: Locking...
25872: Locked. Waiting...
25872: Woken... Spurious.
24928: Locking...
3956: Locking...
3956: Locked. Waiting...
3956: Woken... Spurious.
24928: Locked. Waiting...
24928: Woken... Spurious.
22356: Woken... Waited.
22672: Woken... Waited.
21584: Woken... Waited.
25220: Woken... Waited.
21132: Woken... Waited.
26224: Woken... Waited.
```

However, when I don't provide a predicate and simply check for spurious wakeups after the fact, the program behaves as though spurious wakeups are no longer possible:

**Code**

```cpp
void task(std::size_t i) {
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(cout_mutex);
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": Locking..." << std::endl;
    }

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m[i]);

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(cout_mutex);
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": Locked. Waiting..." << std::endl;
    }

    cv[i].wait(l);

    check_data(i);
}
```

**Output**

```
23592: Locking...
23592: Locked. Waiting...
20388: Locking...
20388: Locked. Waiting...
26536: Locking...
26536: Locked. Waiting...
18436: Locking...
18436: Locked. Waiting...
1528: Locking...
1528: Locked. Waiting...
21236: Locking...
21236: Locked. Waiting...
11784: Locking...
11784: Locked. Waiting...
21776: Locking...
21776: Locked. Waiting...
20796: Locking...
20796: Locked. Waiting...
21472: Locking...
21472: Locked. Waiting...
23988: Locking...
23988: Locked. Waiting...
24988: Locking...
24988: Locked. Waiting...
20388: Woken... Waited.
23592: Woken... Waited.
21236: Woken... Waited.
26536: Woken... Waited.
21472: Woken... Waited.
11784: Woken... Waited.
```

Is thisan unusual implementation detail of MSVC, the intended behavior of `std::condition_variable`, or simply a bug?

P.S. I am aware the main thread may emit notifications before the task threads wait on them. I considered the 1 second delay sufficient mitigation for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the "spurious wakeups" you see in the first example are actually spurious wakeups. If you look at [wait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) the example implementation clearly shows that the predicate is executed before actually blocking on the CV. There are exactly 12 spurious wakeups in the log - for your 12 threads. Each thread checks the predicate first, before actually blocking.

Your detection logic for when a spurious wakeup occurred has false positives.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. In that case, is there any other reliable way to trigger spurious wakeups? I remember them occurring frequently when I was using `pthread`s and such, but I can't seem to observe one on Windows with `std::thread`s.